# Spring login redirects me to the login page, even if the page I'm seeing is not protected

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem. When I start my application and I type for the first time, for example wwww.sitename.com/index, I'm redirected to the login page. Then, if I type again wwww.sitename.com/index I'm redirect to the index page.

Probably I have an error in my configuration, but I can't understand what's wrong

```
    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-authentication-error-url="/login" >
           <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </security:session-management>          

    <security:form-login 
            login-page="/login"         
            default-target-url="/index" 
            always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"                 
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="customFailureHandler"   
            username-parameter="j_username"         
            password-parameter="j_password" />          

    <security:logout
             logout-success-url="/login"                             
             delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" 
             invalidate-session="true" />                               

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/prv/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" /> 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

According to my **intercept-url**, I should be able to reach all the pages that are not under **prv** and **admin** folders without logging, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I think is the first statement.

```
    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-authentication-error-url="/login" >
```

Here you say, if user provides an invalid session ID, then he should be redirected to loging page. When you visit the page after a while and while this your session is expired, this can happen. Try to delete all cookies and visit the page again.

Comment: The problem seems to be invalid-session-url="/login". I delete it and now the problem seems solved.

Answer (score 1):

Spring security starts evaluating your intercept-url pattern in declaration order and stops in the first match.  So in your case, it matches the first line

`<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />`

with every request and stops there giving free permission to everything. It has no chance to evaluate the other expressions.

When defining intercept urls you must add more specific patterns first. For example:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/operation-one/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/operation-one/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />     
<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
```

In your case just put the permit-all pattern last

Comment: Thank for your help, but this doens't solve my problem. Even with your solution, the first time I type a "NOT protected url" I'm redirected to the login page. I have  to type it again to be redirected to that url.

Comment: In this case this make no sense. By this example has the order of rules no effect. If you would set the pattern "/**" instead of "/" then it would better if you define this rule as last rule.

Comment: @Selim Ok. Yes you are right. You and  Serge Ballesta were more careful. The code with the single slash is not generic url. /** is so in this case my answer does not make sense.

Comment: I think you should combine the solutions by both Selim Ok and Serge Ballesta to make it work

Answer (score 1):

`<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />` only allows access for the root URL. If you want to allow access to any URL except those for which you have more restrictive requirements, you should write instead :

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/prv/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" /> 
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" /> 
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```

As currently written, URL `index` was not caught by any `intercept-url` clause.